# MySQL COUNT CASE (count the total occurrance of value in a column)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I would like to count the number of GPS points in `plt_distinct` table based on the mode of transportation in `labels` table:

```
 CREATE TABLE `plt_distinct` (
  `directory` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `latitude` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `longitude` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `flag` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `altitude` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `passeddate` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gpsdate` date ,
  `gpstime` time ,
  `gpsdatetime` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`directory`,`latitude`,`longitude`,`gpsdate`,`gpstime`,`altitude`)
);

CREATE TABLE `labels` (
  `directory` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `starttime` datetime ,  
  `endtime` datetime ,
  `transportationmode` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`directory`,`starttime`,`endtime`,`transportationmode`)
);

INSERT INTO labels (directory, starttime, endtime, transportationmode) 
VALUES (010, '2007-06-26 11:32:29', '2007-06-26 11:40:29','bus'), 
(010, '2008-03-28 14:52:54', '2008-03-28 15:59:59', 'train'),
(010, '2008-03-29 01:27:50', '2008-03-29 15:59:59', 'train'),
(010, '2008-03-31 16:00:08', '2008-03-31 16:09:01', 'taxi'),
(010, '2008-04-01 00:48:32', '2008-04-01 00:59:23', 'taxi');

INSERT INTO plt_distinct (directory, latitude, longitude, flag, altitude, 
passeddate,gpsdate, gpstime, gpsdatetime)
VALUES (010, 18.254638, 109.500127, 0, 26, 39347.6212037037, '2007-09-22', 
'14:54:32', '2007-09-22 14:54:32'),
(010, 18.254665, 109.500092, 0, 36, 39347.6212268519, '2007-09-22', 
'14:54:34', '2007-09-22 14:54:34'),
(010, 18.254925, 109.499998, 0, 44, 39347.6213078704, '2007-09-22', 
'14:54:41', '2007-09-22 14:54:41'),
(010, 18.255035, 109.499972, 0, 38, 39347.6213310185, '2007-09-22',
'14:54:43', '2007-09-22 14:54:43');
```

Then I write:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), CASE( WHEN transportationmode='bus' THEN 'bus', 
                       WHEN transportationmode='car' OR transportationmode='taxi' THEN 'car', 
                       WHEN transportationmode='train' THEN 'train') 
              END AS mode 
FROM plt_distinct JOIN labels USING(directory);

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHEN transportationmode='bus' THEN 'bus', WHEN transportationmode='car' OR trans' at line 1
```

**EDIT**

I produce a db-fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=bd1d97fb1dae54cefd0f8e335e2c522b) with sample data.

Comment: Brackets which wraps CASE alternatives are errorneous. And ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.

Comment: @Strawberry Apology, I made a mistake pasting the query results o overflow.

Comment: @Akina can you elaborate on your comment?

Comment: @Strawberry I provide sample data in both tables to enable reproduce the query.

Comment: *Brackets which wraps CASE alternatives are errorneous.* [CASE operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case). No brackets in its syntax. *And ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.* `COUNT(*)` causes implicit GROUP BY. But `mode` expression does not use any aggregate function. Which contradicts with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL mode setting, or gives unpredictable result when this mode is disabled. *I provide sample data in both tables to enable reproduce the query.* NO. Sample data must be CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts.

Comment: @Strawberry I don't think time spent trying to understand things you don't know can be counted as wast.

Comment: @Akina created this db-fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=bd1d97fb1dae54cefd0f8e335e2c522b

Comment: It seems unlikely that latitude and longitude would form part of a PRIMARY KEY - unless a gps can be in two different places at the same time.

Comment: Likewise, it seems unlikely that endtime would form part of a PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: @Strawberry I am simply working with the schema here: http://elifelog.org/book/microsoft-geolife-gps-trajectories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need fix some syntax and use `group by` . . . and MySQL allows you to use a column alias:

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
       (CASE WHEN l.transportationmode IN ('bus', 'train') THEN l.transportationmode
             WHEN l.transportationmode IN ('car', 'taxi') THEN 'car' 
        END) AS mode 
FROM plt_distinct d JOIN 
     labels l
     USING (directory)
GROUP BY mode;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f6610cb3b9be19317f5de9ac634ffaf4) is a db<>fiddle.

Notes:

- Your `CASE` has extraneous commas and parentheses which this fixes.
- Although your basic logic for the `CASE`, `IN` is simpler than chaining `=`/`OR`s together -- and often has better performance.
- This simplifies the number of `CASE` conditions.
- All column references are *qualified*, meaning that the table is part of the name.

Comment: This gives this error  `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
             WHEN transportationmode IN ('car', 'taxi') THEN 'car' 
           ' at line 2`

Comment: @super_ask . . . It works.  I added a db<>fiddle link.

Comment: thank you for this answer with detailed explaination.

Comment: just to clear my doubt please, why do I end up with `4 bus, 8 car 8 train`  when I have only 5 `rows` in `labels`  and 4 in  `plt_distinct`..?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
SELECT mode, COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        CASE transportationmode
            WHEN 'taxi' THEN 'car'
            ELSE transportationmode
        END AS mode 
    FROM plt_distinct 
    JOIN labels USING(directory)
) t1
GROUP BY mode;
```

Comment: CASE may be simplified to `CASE transportationmode WHEN  'taxi' THEN 'car' ELSE transportationmode END`. And remove a bracket between `'train'` and `END`.

Comment: @RusArtM thank you for your help. I produce a db-fiddle and used your answer giving an error. db-fiddle here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=bd1d97fb1dae54cefd0f8e335e2c522b

Comment: Fixed syntax. Removed odd commas and a bracket. @super_ask please check it again. Should work.

Comment: The wrapper is unnecessary.

Comment: Yes it works, but I'm getting kind of confused, two tables with `5 rows` and `4 rows` how comes I get `4 bus, 8 car 8 train` ? Shouldn't that suppose to be distinct count?

Comment: I beleive this is becouse you are joinin by `directory` which equals to `010` for each row. So it is multiplied.